# On modal open - blurred background vs. dark background

Tags: popup, modal

Are there any difference (advantages / disadvantages) between a darkened background and a blurred background when a modal popup is open? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the modal content in my opinion... you obviously want it to be consistent across the platform, but in cases where the data behind the modal might need to be peeked at, I simply put a 20-30% opacity layer on the background so that users could still see the content if needed.

Comment: This is essentially correct in terms of usability

Answer (score 1):

I recommend blurred background cos the content on the modal pop up will highlight better. User can concentrate on the primary content. Refer the attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that it will only work in situations where the dialog can exist independently of the context. In any webpage, opening a modal comes from certain action , and many times you need to see the content to have a reference, otherwise you'll need to close the modal to see the context. Please note the difference between *dialog* and *modal* as well